# How to compress saves in R package build

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools, roxygen2

I'm trying to include a (somewhat) large dataset in an R package. I keep getting the Warning during the check in Rstudio saying that I could save space with compression:

```
* checking data for ASCII and uncompressed saves ... WARNING

  Note: significantly better compression could be obtained
        by using R CMD build --resave-data
          old_size new_size compress
  slp.rda    499Kb    310Kb    bzip2
  sst.rda    1.3Mb    977Kb       xz
```

I've tried adding `-- resave-data` to RStudio's "Configure Buid Tools" to no effect.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `devtools` function `use_data` takes a parameter for the type of compression and makes adding data to pkgs much easier in general. Using it, or just `save` on your own), use `xz` compression when you save your data (for `save` it's the `compression_level` parameter).

If you want to use `--resave-data` then you can try `--resave-data=best` since just using `--resave-data` defaults to `gzip` (gaining you pretty much nothing in this case).

See [Building package tarballs](https://cran.rstudio.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Building-package-tarballs) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I have tried `save` with compression. The compression error is now gone, but now I get the warning: `Warning: package needs dependence on R (>= 2.10)`. Any experience with that?

Comment: That's due to the extra compression. Add `R (>= 2.10)` to your `DESCRIPTION` file.

Answer (score 12):

Another alternative, if you have a large dataset that you don't want to re-create, is to use `tools::resaveRdaFiles` from within R.  Point it at the dataset file, or the entire data directory, and it will compress your data in a format of your choosing.  See its [manual page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/tools/html/checkRdaFiles.html) for more information.